# Using jasypt to encrypt passwords will randomly start to fail on checkPassword for StrongPasswordEncryption

Tags: java, encryption, jasypt

The code is simple:

```
public static String encryptedPassword(String password)
{
    return new StrongPasswordEncryptor().encryptPassword(password);
}

public static boolean checkPassword(String password, String encryptedPassword)
{
    return new StrongPasswordEncryptor().checkPassword(password, encryptedPassword);
}
```

And it mostly works but then suddenly a valid password that was working for days will suddenly fail and the check password will return false. It can be a day, it can be many days, but eventually the checkPassword for the same encryptedPassword String will one day stop working and return false.

Comment: Can you give an example of values of `password` and `encryptedPassword` that stopped working?

Comment: It's not password specific, it can happen with different random passwords. We experienced it with different users and different test data. I suspect it's due to how the algorithm is seeded in that if you restart the web server it no longer works...

Comment: But can you give an example of values of `password` and `encryptedPassword` for which `new StrongPasswordEncryptor().checkPassword(password, encryptedPassword)` returned true and now return false? Any one will do. If you can show a hardcoded statement in an interactive console returning different values on different runs, that’s even better – it rules out a lot.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?